# Absolute symlink-resolving pwd

Tags: linux, bash, symlink

I'm sitting in front of a Linux shell. I want to do something like `pwd`, except I want an absolute answer, i.e. I want any symlinks to be resolved to their true path. How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to use `pwd -P`

```
tony@matrix:/var/vhosts$ pwd
/var/vhosts
tony@matrix:/var/vhosts$ pwd -P
/srv/data/vhosts
```